# Setup webjob ServiceBusTriggers or queue names at runtime (without hard-coded attributes)?

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

Is there any way to configure triggers without attributes? I cannot know the queue names ahead of time.

Let me explain my scenario here.. I have one service bus queue, and for various reasons (complicated duplicate-suppression business logic), the queue messages have to be processed one at a time, so I have `ServiceBusConfiguration.OnMessageOptions.MaxConcurrentCalls` set to 1. So processing a message holds up the whole queue until it is finished. Needless to say, this is suboptimal.

This 'one at a time' policy isn't so simple. The messages could be processed in parallel, they just have to be divided into groups (based on a field in message), say `A` and `B`. Group `A` can process its messages one at a time, and group `B` can process its own one at a time, etc. `A` and `B` are processed in parallel, all is good.

So I can create a queue for each group, `A`, `B`, `C`, `...` etc. There are about 50 groups, so 50 queues.

I can create a queue for each, but how to make this work with the Azure Webjobs SDK? I don't want to copy-paste a method for each queue with a different `ServiceBusTrigger` for the SDK to discover, just to enforce one-at-a-time per queue/group, then update the code with another copy-paste whenever another group is needed. Fetching a list of queues at startup and tying to the function is preferable.

I have looked around and I don't see any way to do what I want. The `ITypeLocator` interface is pretty hard-set to look for attributes. I could probably abuse the `INameResolver`, but it seems like I'd still have to have a bunch of near-duplicate methods around. Could I somehow create what the SDK is looking for at startup/runtime?

(To be clear, I know how to use INameResolver to get queue name as at [How to set Azure WebJob queue name at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22721491) but though similar this isn't my problem. I want to setup triggers for multiple queues at startup for the same function to get the one-at-a-time per queue processing, without using the trigger attribute 50 times repeatedly. I figured I'd ask again since the SDK repo is fairly active and it's been a year..).

Or am I going about this all wrong? Being dumb? Missing something? Any advice on this dilemma would be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

The Azure Webjob Host discovers and indexes the functions with the `ServiceBusTrigger` attribute when it starts. So there is no way to set up the queues to trigger at the runtime.

The simpler solution for you is to create a long time running job and implement it manually:

```
public class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        var host = new JobHost();
        host.CallAsync(typeof(Program).GetMethod("Process"));
        host.RunAndBlock();
    }

    [NoAutomaticTriggerAttribute]
    public static async Task Process(TextWriter log, CancellationToken token)
    {
        var connectionString = "myconnectionstring";
        // You can also get the queue name from app settings or azure table ??
        var queueNames = new[] {"queueA", "queueA" };
        var messagingFactory = MessagingFactory.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);
        foreach (var queueName in queueNames)
        {
            var receiver = messagingFactory.CreateMessageReceiver(queueName);
            receiver.OnMessage(message =>
            {
                try
                {
                    // do something
                    ....

                    // Complete the message
                    message.Complete();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // Log the error
                    log.WriteLine(ex.ToString());

                    // Abandon the message so that it can be retry.
                    message.Abandon();
                }
            }, new OnMessageOptions() { MaxConcurrentCalls = 1});
        }

        // await until the job stop or restart
        await Task.Delay(Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan, token);
    }
}
```

Otherwise, if you don't want to deal with multiple queues, you can have a look at [azure servicebus topic/subscription](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-dotnet-how-to-use-topics-subscriptions/) and create SqlFilter to send your message to the right subscription.

Another option could be to create your own trigger: The azure webjob SDK provides extensibility points to create your own trigger binding :

- [Binding Extensions Overview](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/wiki/Binding-Extensions-Overview)

Good Luck !

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding, your needs seems to be building a message batch system in parallel. The @Thomas solution is good, but I think [Azure Batch](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/batch-technical-overview/) service with Table storage may be better and could be instead of the complex solution of ServiceBus queue + WebJobs with a trigger.

Using Azure Batch with Table storage, you can control the task creation and execute the task in parallel and at scale, even monitor these tasks, please refer to the [tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/batch-dotnet-get-started/) to know how to.