# Azure Functions QueueTrigger with variable name, QueueTriggerAttribute restrictions

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, azure-functions

Assume the following typical [Queue Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue#trigger---c-example) function:

```
public void Run([QueueTrigger("queue1")]object data, ILogger log)
{
    // Do something with data
}
```

My problem is that `"queue1"` has to be a constant field, so it has to be defined at compile time.
Also, I'd want to have a base class for Queue Triggers, that could work like this:

```
public abstract class QueueBase<TModel>
{
    public void Run([QueueTrigger("queueName")]TModel data, ILogger log)
    {
        // Do something with data, log something etc.
        OnRunExecuted(data);
        // Do something with data, log something etc.
    }

    public abstract void OnRunExecuted(TModel data);
}
```

with this, I could write own classes which inherit from `QueueBase` but can even live inside a library which doesn't have `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs` dependency:

```
public class MyQueueHandler : QueueBase<MyModel>
{
    public void OnRunExecuted(MyModel data) => ...;
}
```

But it's impossible to pass in a Queue name... is it?

Answer (score 2):

See [binding expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-expressions-patterns):

In short, you can pass in a variable queue name as "%queue-name-variable%"

```
[FunctionName("QueueTrigger")]
public static void Run(
    [QueueTrigger("%queue-name-variable%")]string myQueueItem, 
    ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation($"C# Queue trigger function processed: {myQueueItem}");
}
```

Where **input-queue-name** is defined in your configuration like

```
{"queue-name-variable": "queue-name-in-current-env"}
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, I understand there is that option. I want the classes I write to be more flexible though, and having "queue-name-variable" always map to one specific other value (per environment) isn't very helpful. And the problem with the `INameResolver` is, that it doesn't provide any context of resolution, so within method `Resolve (string name)` you don't have much to decide upon.

Comment: Exactly, writing trigger function for each queue is so arcane. Several requests are made asking for dynamic handling of queue name in the trigger function. You can also upvote my request [here](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/6ec830d8-b3b9-ed11-a81b-000d3ae6a6aa)

Answer (score 1):

As i remember attribute **QueueTrigger** accept only const string, so you can try make some tricks using environment variables like in post [how to pass dynamic queue name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50148862/is-there-a-way-to-dynamically-determine-the-amount-and-names-of-queues-triggered)